# How to call a particular interface method that have multiple implementation

Tags: java, spring

I am going to ask my previous question in different way. I have a interface with multiple implementation (2-3 classes are implement same interface). I want to run a method can anyone tell me how can we decide which method should be call. when we are taking the reference of the interface.

Comment: can you explain what you mean how can we decide wht method should be call

Comment: Please show a short example of what you mean.

Comment: i am taking a interface nodeservice and the nodeservice interface is implemented by dbnodeserviceimpl and nodeserviceimpl classes and in both one setproperty method is present  i just create a new class and extend dbnodeserviceimpl class and redefined the set property method in our class and i just want to call that method with the help of nodeservice interface note:-i am not creating any instance i am just injecting a bean of nodeservice and dirctly i am calling that method i dont know which method is called

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try considering profiles in your project 
 ex :- 
 you have 2 classes

```
@Profile("dev")
class dev implement something{

}

@profile("live")
class live implement something{

}

---------------------------------

in your application context register the active profile to be picked
appcontext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("live");

---------------------------------

using the active profile 
public void doSomething(something somethin){
somethin.//yourmethod
}
```